# jquery dropdown menu & swf

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flash

I've built a jQuery dropdown menu to float over a banner swf.  For some reason in ie6 & ie7, the menu rolls behind the swf.

I've tried the `wmode=transparent` in the code to load the flash file with no avail.  I've also tried `z-index` in the css with the menu above the swf.  No luck.

How I make the menu be in front of the swf?

Answer (score 2):

Check the following:

- Did you set `wmode="opaque"` to both the `object` and the `embed` tag?
- Does the dropdown menu's `div` has a `z-index` greater than the `object`/`embed` tag?

Comment: i'm using swfobject to load my swf.
this is my code...

<script type="text/javascript">
 var flashvars = {};
 var params = {};
 params.wmode = "transparent";
 var attributes = {};
 attributes.id = "flash_header";
 swfobject.embedSWF("test.swf", "flash_header", "898", "265", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>

the dropdown menu has a greater value z-ndex. should the div holding the swf have index as well?

Comment: The div holding the swf should have a lower z-index than the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be the dreaded [IE6 z-index bug](http://20.targetprocess.com/2006/07/ie6-select-and-z-index-problem.html)?

Comment: possibly. works fine ie8, firefox and mac browsers. i hate ie

Answer (score 0):

You could set `wmode` to `opaque`.  There's more information on [projectseven.com](http://www.projectseven.com/support/answers.asp?id=127)